# Getting data from Firebase database when auth.id == $uid not working

Tags: android, database, firebase

I am trying to get data from Firebase database in Android app so that only those data created by currently authenticated user is visible, with following code.

```
{
  "rules": {
      "events": {
         "$userId": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $userId",
            ".write": "auth.uid == $userId",
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The database looks like this:

```
root
    events
        event1
            city
            date
            userID
        event2
            city
            date
            userID
```

There is no User "table". But users login through Firebase UI and so, there accounts are created by FirebaseAuth with uid.

I am trying to get data from following line:

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("events");
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Event event = new Event();
                event = dataSnapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                eventList.add(event);
                eventListRecyclerView.setAdapter(EventAdapter);
            }
```

I get no data back when do accordingly.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have taken wrong child because *root is **rules** and child is **events*** 
you never call child directly without parent

may i think below code solve your problem

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child.("rules").child("events");
```

Comment: But those rules are the database access rules, not the database structure itself. The structure is root -> events.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself.
My database structure was not correct. It should be

```
root
    <uid>
        events
           ...
```

And the database reference code should be

```
mContactsDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("events").child(new FirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```